# getSubImage outside Raster

Tags: exception, bufferedimage, raster

I have an image that has a width of 512px. This piece of code will throw

```
RasterFormatException   (x+width) is outside Raster
```

I dont understand what im doing wrong, when i check the raster size it says its 512

```
private void automaticStaticSpriteLoader(String loadedName, String imgLoc, BufferedImage[] biArray, int numberOfSpritesToLoad, int numberOfSpritesInImage, int percentComplete){
    try {
        temporaryBigImg = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(imgLoc + ".png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(classNumber + " Error Loading Sprite Images. Shutting Down.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<numberOfSpritesToLoad;i++){
        biArray[i] = temporaryBigImg.getSubimage(counterX, counterY, 32, 32);
        System.out.println("CounterX = " + counterX + " CounterY = " + counterY + " Current Index = " + i);
        if(counterX == 512){
            counterY += 32;
            counterX = -32;
        }
        counterX+=32;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating `counterX`and `counterY` too late.

You have to check if `counterX >= 512` and eventually increment `counterY` and reset `counterX` *before* you call `getSubImage`.

The code, as in your post will first call `getSubImage(512, 0, 32, 32)`, then test if `counterX == 512` (but the test is never reached). Try printing the actual values you pass in, and you will see what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt realize it was on 512 (which is the end of the image)

Comment: I think it's quite annoying that the exception message doesn't contain the actual values for x and width in this case, it would have been so much easier to debug..